# Travelling from the UK to Spain, have lost passport, any ideas?

Tags: air-travel, europe, passports, business-travel, emergencies

Travelling from the UK to Spain, have lost passport, any ideas?

Comment: The most important information you didn't give is your nationality

Comment: @Vince I'm British, added to answer

Comment: When I was in a similar experience this time last year there was a same day service for renewal, did they not offer this?  We booked a last minute trip, only to find youngest child's passport expired a month before the others so was done.  I booked passport office for same day service, only to find children only on week service.  Mind you the wife nearly kissed the courier when the passports arrived at 7:45 the day we were due to leave (2 hours before we were due to leave to go to the airport).  The status line they tell you to phone doesn't get info until a week after applying so don't bother

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager This isn't offered in the case of a lost passport, only a renewal

Comment: Ahh, right.  Still keep fingers crossed, they do surprise you sometimes.  Given also many English schools are already on holidays, the demand may be dropping off.  We were told it all depends on demand at the printing centre, the offices don't do their own any more, and if it doesn't get stuck being put into the print queue it should go through quickly.

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager Cheers, yeah keeping my fingers crossed!

Comment: Not a proper answer but you may want to check the requirements for crossing in the tunnel shuttle. Once you are in France it is a 10 hour drive to Spain ( plus up to another 10 hours depending on your destination in mainland Spain)

Comment: Also, what about the return trip? Maybe you could have some luck with French or Spanish border guards but the UK is notoriously paranoid about immigration, not sure any airline would take chances bringing you back there.

Comment: @Relaxed, his old UK passport will work for getting back in.

Answer (score 1):

As you are British, you are from the EU, and you only need a national identity card to enter the Schengen area (Spain in your case).

According to [this good Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Schengen_Area#Visa_exemptions) on the Scengen visa policy, you should even ["be afforded every reasonable opportunity to obtain the necessary documents or have them brought to them within a reasonable period of time or corroborate or prove by other means that he/she is covered by the right of free movement."](http://register.consilium.europa.eu/doc/srv?l=EN&f=ST%2015010%202006%20INIT) "checks on persons enjoying the Community right of free movement should be limited, as a general rule, to the verification of their identity and nationality."

In other words, you can go with your national ID (is your driver license your national ID?) or take all the documents you have (if no national id) including the receipt from the passport office stating you have lost and asked for a new passport. Explaining your situation, and given the wording used, there might not be any issue, at least, it is worth trying.

As @Relaxed mentioned, the problem may also come from the airline staff. While the border guard may allow you in, the airline staff may also require some specific ID documents. You should check your airline website what piece of ID is required. My opinion is that in the end you should still try to go and see.

Comment: Unfortunately the UK ID cards were so mishandled they never became widely available.  A driving licence doesn't count, I asked about that (see comment on main question).

Comment: There is no general national ID card scheme in the UK. Also, the bits in the Schengen regulations about proving your citizenship at the border only apply if you make it to the border. Airlines are not bound by it and probably won't take chances. Even if any of this occasionally works, I don't think you can be confident that “there should not be any issue“.

Comment: @Relaxed I agree I have been trying to make it sound more like "this is worth trying flying there".

Comment: Fair enough, +1

Comment: @Eugene I think the issue is not what nationality you have, but more how to prove it. In the Border Guard document, they list national ID or passports are usual pieces of ID. Maybe other documents would work but this is not systematically accepted. So in the end, it depends on the border police, and as Relaxed says, a lot on the airline staff.

Comment: @pnuts For some time, being born in Northern Ireland was enough to also be a citizen of the Republic of Ireland. This was changed as a response to [Chen v. Home Secretary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chen_v_Home_Secretary) and it's arguably not terribly relevant in this case but being born in Northern Ireland does make a difference as far as citizenship is concerned.